# masonry overlaping images - try all tutorial but nothing

Tags: jquery-masonry, overlapping

I have :

```
<div id="container" class="masonry js-masonry">



            <div class="item">
                <a href="example.com7images/imageFullsize.jpg"><img width="128" alt="image.jpg" class="image" src="small/thumb_Jennifer_Aniston-wallpaper.jpg"></a>                   
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <a href="example.com7images/imageFullsize.jpg"><img width="128" alt="image.jpg" class="image" src="small/thumb_Jennifer_Aniston-wallpaper.jpg"></a>                   
            </div>

    </div>
```

and:

```
         <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry;
// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  msnry = new Masonry( container );
});
</script>
```

Masonry work as axpected but images overlap.after I  rezise the browser they show in the right way.

**What is wrong? How shoud I do it?**

Comment: found the answer:<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.item',
            });
        });
    });
  });
</script> BUT imagesLoaded does not work on my second div container.(I added a second div container with the same content). ANY HELP WILL BE APRECIATED.

Comment: problem solved.


full solution here -html and script:


  https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/445

Comment: workin example: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qDtIr